# What's the feedback regulation of Thyroid diseases and body temperature?

Tags: endocrinology, temperature, homeostasis

While going through the feedback regulation, the control of blood glucose level by insulin and glucagon is quite discussed in multiple materials including the textbook. I also understand the basic fever and cold feedback regulation with regards to hypothalumus given in the below picture.

[image]

But I am not able to find either a digram or a material that explains the **relationship between hypothalamus, pituitary gland and thyroid gland in controling temperature**<sup>1</sup>, specially for those who are suffering from thyroid diseases. e.g. *some people with thyroid issues feel too cold or too hot (fingers, hands, legs, skin is quickly cold or hot depending on the external change). Their body seem to fail in maintaining the set point of temperature.*

What's the endocrine and feedback regulation behind this<sup>1</sup> scenario? What's the hormone pathway? Also in terms of energy, heat and metabolism.